# How to access a single json post via an url parameter using php?

Tags: php, json

I am currently stuck with this problem while trying to create a RESTFUL API using PHP without any frameworks or databases. I parsed the JSON data with PHP, but I am having trouble with trying to access a certain post depending on what query parameter you type to the URL.

So this is my php code:

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header ('Content-Type: application/json');
$jsondata = file_get_contents("credits.json");  
print_r(json_encode($jsondata));
?>
```

And this is my json data:

```
{
"credits": [
      {
        "creditId": 123,
        "id": 1,
        "client": "Peter",
      },
      {
        "creditId": 789,
        "id": 2,
        "client": "Jonas",
      }
   ]
}
```

For instance: if my URL looks like this: http://localhost:5041/credits/, typing http://localhost:5041/credits/?id=1 would access only a single post with the certain id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = '{
"credits": [
      {
        "creditId": 123,
        "id": 1,
        "client": "Peter"
      },
      {
        "creditId": 789,
        "id": 2,
        "client": "Jonas"
      }
   ]
}';

$data = json_decode($data,true);

$row  = array_keys(array_combine(array_keys($data['credits']), array_column($data['credits'], 'id')),$_GET['id']);

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    print_r($data['credits'][$row[0]]);
}
else{
    print_r($data);
}
```

First step is to decode your json into an array. Then using the php array functions i am searching in your multidimensional array for the value that you receive from your url using `$_GET['id']` and print only the block that has this id , otherwise print the whole array.

Just like you asked your url will work for all the results if you don't put any id and will work for the specific results that belong to this id if you set an id in the url.